# Is there a way to create SQLite query to delete a String in a cell? Because in that cell there are more than one value which inserted in StringBuilder

Tags: java, android

I want to create a method in SQLite database class to delete a particular String of text in a cell. Let's say I have a row in SQLite database like this image

[image]

And in the CONTENT column I have inserted 4 Strings using StringBuilder class that they are separated using a new line during insertion process. In the first row in column Content I have these values like below image
[image]

Here I want to delete for example item b, not the entire row, because deleting the entire row is simple and I don't want that.
Deleting the entire row, inserting a row like that and showing that in RecyclerView works properly, but what I want to know is deleting a specific String in a specified row. Any help appreciated. I have searched a ton, but in vain.

Comment: Just update the row.

Comment: Get the entire row from the database. Edit the entire line. Update the entire row in the database. There is no standard way to replace part of a cell's row in SQLite.